# Google Packaged App Native Messaging

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chrome-native-messaging

I have a windows console application and a chrome packaged app that I am trying to get two way communication going with. I've followed the example they have with the python app but I have not had any luck.

I've taken the following steps:

1. Created this entry in my registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\NativeMessagingHosts:
   my.app.name : c:\path\to\my.app.name.json
2. I've created the json file at that location:
   {
   "name": "my.app.name",
   "description": "Chrome Native Messaging API",
   "path": "c:\path\to\my.app.name\consoleApp.exe",
   "type": "stdio",
   "allowed_origins": [
   "chrome-extension://offmjeicniagcebcbclkdlkllfibllfh/"
   ]
   }
3. I have added the following in my packaged app script:

   ```
   function connect() {
    var hostName = "my.app.name";
    appendMessage("Connecting to native messaging host <b>" + hostName + "</b>")
    port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
    port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);        
   }

   function appendMessage(text) {
    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += "<p>" + text + "</p>";
   }

   function onNativeMessage(message) {
     appendMessage("Received message: <b>" + message + "</b>");
   }

   function onDisconnected() {
    appendMessage("Failed to connect: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    port = null;
   }
   ```

When I click a button that calls the connect function I get this error:

***"Invalid native messaging host name specified"***

I've tried playing with this every way I can think of but there is just not much documentation or sample code (almost none). Does anyone have any ideas?

thanks

Comment: *Comment from [user3174625](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3174625/user3174625)*: How you're receiving the messages in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got it worked! Try to change "path" to "consoleApp.exe" (with all my previous suggestions) and put your app into the same folder as app's manifest. Then check task manager and you will see your process worked. Good luck.

Comment: This was very helpful thanks. I also found that there is, as far as I can tell, an undocumented requirement regarding the naming convention of the host. My host was named something like "myHostingApplication". When I changed it to "my.hosting.application" this began to work. Google can have whatever restrictions they like on naming conventions but when they do not document it they make life miserable.

Comment: You right. I changed my one to "com.google.chrome.myexample" and I this it was one of the positive changes.

Comment: I recently went back to this for further testing. Another requirement for the host name is that it MUST be all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I think you missed "Chrome" in registry path between "Google" and "NativeMessagingHosts". And as I understood, my.app.name should be a key but not a value.
Anyway, it didn't help for me :(
I also created the same keys for x64 and x86 registry keys.

Comment: I've had a similar problem with this error message. I've look on Chromium sources, and found out that this error is triggered only on few problems: 1) can't locate registry value that should point to the manifest file, 2) can't open manifest file, 3) can't parse manifest file, 4) the name in the manifest doesn't match, 5) executable file is not absolute (but it MAY be relative on Windows). You may use tools like SysInternals ProcMon to find out if Chrome loads the setting from Registry, opens your manifest file, etc. It helped me ;) -- I had a syntax error in manifest's json file.